# Switch CSS stylesheet based on viewport size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've followed instructions at CSS-Tricks to change stylesheets based on viewport width using multiple .css files and jQuery, but my code is not working. I've sat here analyzing this for an hour, and can't catch my error. Can anybody see what I'm doing incorrectly? Thank you in advance for any help offered!

```js
function adjustStyle(width) {
  width = parseInt(width);
  if (width > 901) {
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "large.css");
  } else {
     $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "small.css"); 
  }
}

$(function() {
  adjustStyle($(this).width());
  $(window).resize(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
  });
});
```

```css
body {
 background-image: url(large_pic.jpg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Practice Responsiveness</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="large.css" />
  <link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="small.css" />
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="practice.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not just use media queries?

Comment: j08691, I tried that too, and couldn't get it to work! I'm new at this stuff, so once I figure out how to get the jQuery solution to work, I'm going to tackle the media query solution...

Comment: @MizzKFizzle skip the jQuery part; the knowledge doesn't transfer to media queries, and the media query option is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the media attribute:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 900px)" href="small.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(min-width: 901px)" href="large.css" />
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

Comment: Alright--got it to work, and I can now see that this is the best solution. Thanks for your help!